# I can't find the source of this Segmentation Fault: 11 error

Tags: c++, opencv, memory

I do realize that there are many posts on this error, but I've looked through several of these and still can't seem to apply them to my own code. I think I'm having some sort of memory error, but I don't know what's causing it or how to resolve it. I've included the segment of code that I think is causing the problem. Here's what the code is supposed to do: I've segmented an image into different colored patches (this works successfully). Now I want the user to be able to click on a patch and have the whole patch be colored light purple. The recoloring should extend to the border of the selected patch, or to the edge of the image, whichever comes first. The function included below takes the x,y coordinate of the mouse click, and the id (determined by color) of the patch the user clicked. It adds the pixel corresponding to this x,y coordinate to a stack, and then sees if there are any pixels with the same id directly adjacent to our pixel which have not yet been recolored. If there are, we call the function again on that pixel. When we find ourselves with no new pixels to move on to, we pop that pixel from the stack and return to the last pixel we haven't exhausted yet. The reason I think this is a memory error is that my function actually works on small colored patches, but freaks out when it has to recolor large patches. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
void recurse(int x, int y, int runs,int label){

    //0 is the 0 row, 0 col --> 1 is the 1st row, 0th col
    cout << "in recurse" << endl;
    //int label = labels.at<int>(y + x*my_img.rows,0);
    cout << "that label " << label << endl;
    cout << "vec size " << uncolored.size() << endl;
    cout << "runs " << runs << endl;
    pixel tempPixel(x,y);

    //add this to the list of potential spots if new
    cout << "patched current " << patched(x,y) << endl;

    if(patched(x,y) == 0){
        cout << "trying to add " << endl;
        uncolored.push_back(tempPixel);
        cout << "added " << endl;
        my_img.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[0] = 241;
        my_img.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[1] = 217;
        my_img.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[2] = 212;
    }

    //recolor
    bool up_good = true;
    bool down_good = true;
    bool left_good = true;
    bool right_good = true;
    int up = -1;
    int down = -1;
    int left = -1;
    int right = -1;
    //check surroundings

    if((y - 1) < 0){
        up_good = false;
    }
    if((y + 1) >= my_img.cols){
        down_good = false;
    }
    if((x - 1)< 0){
        left_good = false;
    }
    if((x + 1) >= my_img.rows){
        right_good = false;
    }

    if(up_good){
        up = labels.at<int>((y - 1) + x*my_img.rows,0);
    }
    if(down_good){
        down = labels.at<int>((y + 1) + x*my_img.rows,0);
    }
    if(left_good){
        left = labels.at<int>(y + (x - 1)*my_img.rows,0);
    }
    if(right_good){
        right = labels.at<int>(y + (x + 1)*my_img.rows,0);
    }

    /*
     my_img.at<Vec3b>(y - 1,x)[0] = 241;
     my_img.at<Vec3b>(y - 1,x)[1] = 0;
     my_img.at<Vec3b>(y - 1,x)[2] = 0;

     my_img.at<Vec3b>(y + 1,x)[0] = 241;
     my_img.at<Vec3b>(y + 1,x)[1] = 0;
     my_img.at<Vec3b>(y + 1,x)[2] = 0;

     my_img.at<Vec3b>(y,x - 1)[0] = 241;
     my_img.at<Vec3b>(y,x - 1)[1] = 0;
     my_img.at<Vec3b>(y,x - 1)[2] = 0;

     my_img.at<Vec3b>(y,x + 1)[0] = 241;
     my_img.at<Vec3b>(y,x + 1)[1] = 0;
     my_img.at<Vec3b>(y,x + 1)[2] = 0;
     */


     /*if(runs % 1000 == 0){
         cout << "XOX! " << endl;
         imshow("My Window",my_img);
         cvWaitKey(0);
     }*/

    //if that is the same label and not yet purple
    if(up == label and patched(x,y - 1) == 0 and up_good == true){
        //uncolored.push_back(tempPixel);
        cout << "leaving" << endl;
        recurse(x,y - 1,runs + 1,label);
    }
    else if(down == label and patched(x,y + 1) == 0 and down_good == true){
        //uncolored.push_back(tempPixel);
        cout << "leaving" << endl;
        recurse(x,y + 1,runs + 1,label);
    }
    else if(left == label and patched(x - 1,y) == 0 and left_good == true){
        //uncolored.push_back(tempPixel);
        cout << "leaving" << endl;
        recurse(x - 1,y,runs + 1,label);
    }
    else if(right == label and patched(x + 1,y) == 0 and right_good == true){
        //uncolored.push_back(tempPixel);
        cout << "leaving" << endl;
        recurse(x + 1,y,runs + 1,label);
    }
    else{
        // if not surrounded by anything good
        if(uncolored.size() > 1){
            cout << " popping " << endl;
            //this is no longer a good pixel
            uncolored.pop_back();
            cout << " popped " << endl;
            // return to the last good pixel
            cout << " assigning " << endl;
            tempPixel = uncolored[uncolored.size() - 1];
            cout << " assigned " << tempPixel.x << " " << tempPixel.y << endl;

            recurse(tempPixel.x,tempPixel.y,runs + 1,label);
        }
        else{
            cout << " done! " << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: note: the "patched" function checks if a pixel has already been recolored. Pretty sure this part is working fine.

Comment: Does your OS have all current patches applied?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm using a mac, if that helps

Comment: I have seen problems like this resolved by installing current Solaris patches. I do not know about Mac.

Comment: We can't run your example (this is not a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), so it's hard to really help. My advise is to learn to use your debugger (probably LLDB on MacOS). With this tool, you will find 99% of seg fault easily.

Comment: did you debug (or add debug output) to find the actual line of code where you get the segfault? What's the size of the image and what's the size of labels?

Comment: If I see it right, you don't check whether the x or y pos might be < 0 in some of the update code blocks.